# Access web console over OpenVPN on port

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have some services which are installed on my server with a web console running on port 5000. I have setup OpenVPN to access this web console, I am all connected but how do I configure OpenVPN to allow me to access localhost services.

The service is running on local ip e.g. 192.168.0.10:5000 and the VPN server is on 10.8.0.1.

What should I do to now access this or could someone point me in the direction of what do I search for?

Comment: If your vpn is setup correctly and you are connected, you should just be able to access your local net in remote site. What happens when you try to open 192.168.0.10:5000? Can you ping  192.168.0.10?

Comment: Ahhh thank you. I was trying 10.8.0.1:5000. Silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your vpn is setup correctly and you are connected, you should just be able to access your local net in remote site without any extra configuration.

Try to open 192.168.0.10:5000 and it should work.